# .NET SqlParameter constructor inconsistent?

Tags: sql, .net, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

Can anyone tell me what is going on in this function??
In the following code snippet, `user.Id = 0`, `id.Value = 0` and `id.SqlDbType = Int`.. as expected since `user.Id` is an int field.

However, `error.Value = null` and `error.SqlDbType = BigInt`. What gives? If I use non-zero it detects an int and the correct value.

Note: the Value properties are the same before and after declaring the parameter direction.

```
public static long InsertUpdate(User user) {

    SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", user.Id);
    id.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(id);

    SqlParameter error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", 0);
    error.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(error);

    .... other stuff
}
```

As well, if @SET @error_Code = 0 in the sproc, error.Value = NULL and error.SqlDbType = NVarChar AFTER the procedure runs. If I set it to an integer I get an Int type.

UPDATE:
After specifying SqlDbType.Int the parameter now has the correct SqlDbType before and after the command... however the stored procedure is still setting @error_code = null when I in fact set it to 0.

UPDATE: 
When the sproc executes the SELECT statement the @error_code parameter is always returned as null, regardless of when or not it has been set... this only happens when there's a select statement...

Here is the procedure to reproduce:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_user_insert_v1]
    @username VARCHAR(255),
    @password VARCHAR(255),
    @gender CHAR(1),
    @birthday DATETIME,
    @error_code INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @default_dt DATETIME
    EXEC @default_dt = uf_get_default_date
    DECLARE @dt DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()

            INSERT INTO users(username, password, gender, birthday, create_dt, last_login_dt, update_dt, deleted)
            VALUES(@username, @password, @gender, @birthday, @dt, @default_dt, @default_dt, 0)
            SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            SET @error_code = 3
            RETURN

END
```

***SOLUTION?***

http://forums.asp.net/t/1208409.aspx?Interesting+problem+with+getting+OUTPUT+parameters+from+SQL+Server+using+C+

Found this link on the ASP forums... apparently you can't read the output parameter until you have read all the results from the SqlDataReader... very unfortunate for me since I decide whether or not I even WANT to read the results based on the output param...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the current answers are slightly incorrect because they're based on the assumption that the constructor being called for your `error` object is the [`(string,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one. This is not the case. A literal `0` can be converted to any enum type<sup>1</sup>, and such a conversion would be preferred over a conversion to `object`. So the constructor being called is the [`(string,SqlDbType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor.

So the type is set to `BigInt` because that's the `0` value for the [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration, and the `Value` is null because you have no code that attempts to set the value.

```
SqlParameter error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", (object)0);
```

should cause it to select the correct overload.

---

Demo:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var a = new ABC("ignore", 0);
            var b = new ABC("ignore", (object)0);
            var c = new ABC("ignore", 1);
            int i = 0;
            var d = new ABC("ignore", i);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    public class ABC
    {
        public ABC(string ignore, object value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object");
        }

        public ABC(string ignore, SqlDbType value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SqlDbType");
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
SqlDbType
Object
Object
Object
```

---

<sup>1</sup>From the [C# Language specification, version 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 1.10 (that is, just in the *introduction* to the language, not buried deep down in the language lawyery bits):

> In order for the default value of an enum type to be easily available, the literal 0 implicitly converts to any enum type. Thus, the following is permitted.

```
Color c = 0;
```

I'd have also thought this important enough to be in the Language Reference on MSDN but haven't found a definitive source yet.

Comment: Can you explain why SqlParamter("@id", user.Id) creates an Int and not SqlParameter("@error_code", 0)? user.Id is an int field set to 0. Also, SqlParamter("@error_code", 2) correctly creates sets the SqlDataParamter to an int... so I don't think that it's selecting the SqlDataType(name, SqlDbType) constructor when passed an integer literal.

Comment: `user.Id` isn't an integer **literal** in any circumstance. And it's the integer literal `0` that has this special case that allows it to be converted to an `enum` value. And, if you don't believe me, try adding more cases to the sample code I included in my answer, which I did so that you can *see* which overload is chosen for different circumstances.

Comment: Sorry, literal was totally the wrong word. I see your point, strange that other integer literals aren't interpreted as SqlDbType enums.

Comment: @Cailen - have you seen my updates that I've been adding? - it's a specific feature of the language, specifically for `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That explains my last question.

Answer (score 2):

From [SqlParameter.Value on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

> For output and return value parameters, the value is set on completion of the SqlCommand

i.e. I wouldn't rely on type inference to set the return type implicitly.
I would explicitly set the type of the output parameter:

```
var error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", SqlDbType.Int)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
```

**Edit**

After some reflection of `SqlParameter`:

The `BigInt` is easy to explain - it is the default `SqlDbType`, and the `SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)` ctor doesn't overwrite this value.

```
public enum SqlDbType
{
  BigInt = 0,
  ...
```

Re: `@error_code` is returned as NULL

The only thing I can think of is that the PROC fails to complete cleanly. Try moving the `SET @error_code = 0` above the `EXEC @default_dt = uf_get_default_date` ?

**Edit**

Confirmed, @Damien's point is correct

```
SqlParameter error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", 0);
```

Actually calls this ctor:

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType)
```

whereas

```
SqlParameter error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", 1234);
```

calls

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)
```

Reason : [0 is implicitly castable to enum.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043554/method-overload-resolution-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: Maybe this should be a different question, but do you have any idea why the SqlDbType is an NVarChar when my sql procedure declares '@error_code INT OUTPUT' and does SET '@error_code = 0' at the start of the procedure? It seems like it should AT LEAST be setting it to the right datatype after the command executes according to your link.

Comment: Going to open a new question for why my output parameter is being nulled in the sproc (I've verified this happens when a SELECT statement is executed in the procedure, and the output parameter gets set to null regardless of 0 or nonzero).

Def +1 for reminding me of object initializers though.

Comment: The `(string,object)` constructor isn't being called at all, for `error`.

Comment: @Damien well done - indeed, the (string, object) ctor isn't called for zero, but is called for any other INT. [Wow.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043554/method-overload-resolution-unexpected-behavior)

Comment: I like the rest of your answer though so +1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the most reliable way of doing it is by using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
SqlParameter error = new SqlParameter("@error_code", SqlDBType.Int);
error.Value = 0;
```

The overload you're using takes an `object` as a parameter, and for some reason which I can't divine, it's not picking the right type.

Comment: The compiler will prefer to convert `0` to an enumeration type than to convert it to `object`.