# Unexpected behaviour on overload resolving

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

Please, consider the following code:

```
static void foo(object v)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(v.GetType());
}

static void foo(OleDbType v)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(v.GetType());
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foo(1);
    foo(0);
    foo(2);
}
```

The output is:

```
System.Int32
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType
System.Int32
```

So `foo(0)` is resolved to `static void foo(OleDbType)` and the other calls are resolved to `static void foo(object)`

I'd expect all the calls to be resolved to the same method, why this happens?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2043554/5311735

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit conversion from the constant 0 to any enum type, so `foo(0)` matches the overload with the `OleDbType` enum parameter.