# Method Overriding in SqlParameter

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, overloading, sqlparameter

I am using parameterized query in C# with following piece of code:

```
int i = 5;
string query = "select col1 from table where col2 = @prm1 and col3 = @prm2";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prm1", (int)MyEnum.val1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prm2", i);

public enum MyEnum
{
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 100,
    val3 = 150
}
```

Now, the built-in class `SqlParameter` has 2 overloaded method with 2 params as follows :

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType);
   
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, object value);
```

Now, for `@prm2`, where I am passing `int` variable, it's correctly initializing parameter with proper value. But for `@prm1`, where I am passing enum & converting it as `int` as value, it's taking it as 1st method of `SqlParameter`.

Built-in `SqlDbType` enum is as follows:

```
public enum SqlDbType
{
   BigInt = 0,
   Binary = 1,
   ....
   ....
}
```

Since the value of enum I am passing is `0`, it is taking that 0 and using first method and creating a parameter with `BigInt` DATATYPE instead of creating param with value `0`.

What could be the reason behind this? Is it some sort of bug or am I missing some silly point here?

**Update:** Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043554/method-overload-resolution-unexpected-behavior) provides answer to my original question, which says '0 is implicitly convertable to enum, but non-zero value isn't' hence the difference in choosing method for both statements. I've tried following:

```
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prm1", (int)MyEnum.val1));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prm1", Convert.ToInt32(MyEnum.val1)));
```

1st statement calling method with `SqlDbType` arg & 2nd is calling method with `object` value, even though I'm basically passing both values as `int`. Any explaination for that?

Comment: You should always use the first overload anyway, so that you are in control of specifying the datatype and to ensure its consistent every time the query is called - else you can end up with different query plans.

Comment: @DaleK But in order to invoke first method, i supposed to pass 2nd argument of `SqlDbType`, but here in both cases, I am passing `int` & yet diff methods gets invoked for both statements.

Comment: `SqlDbType` is also an enum, which is an int... so I guess the compiler is getting confused around which enum is being used. However if you use the first method correct, by actually specifying a type you will never have an issue.

Comment: @DaleK hmmm...that makes some sense actually. Also, I tried with `Convert.ToInt32(MyEnum.val1)` and it took it as value (method-2) instead of `DbType`. So I guess, there is some sort of precedence is in play here.

Comment: So this only seems to be an issue when the underlying value is 0.  So for instance if you try `(int)DayOfWeek.Monday` it uses the object overload, but for `(int)DayOfWeek.Sunday` it goes with `SqlDbType`.  In fact if you just do `new SqlParameter("name", 0)` that also goes with `SqlDbType`, but any other `int` does not.

Comment: @juharr exactly. Try with `new SqlParameter("name", (int)0)` and  `new SqlParameter("name", Convert.ToInt32(0))` and it will interpret both statements in a different way.

Comment: Yeah, it has to specifically be a constant value of 0.  It technically doesn't know the result of `Convert.ToInt32(0)` until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit clumsy API in my opinion. Just specify it explicitly:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prm1", SqlDbType.Int){ Value = (int)MyEnum.val1}));
```

I usually replace it with extension if not using any ORM or frameworks to build SQL:

```
public static class SqlExtensions
{
    public static SqlParameterCollection Add(this SqlParameterCollection pars, string name, SqlDbType type, object value)
    {
        var res = new SqlParameter(name, type){Value = (value == null ? DbNull.Value)};
        pars.Add(res);
        return pars;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.Int, 123)
              .Add("@b", SqlDbType.BigInt, 234)
              .Add("@c", SqlDbType.Binary, null);
```

Comment: oh yes...offcourse  it'll work if you specifically define the value & datatype. I am just confused with choice of method on runtime by compiler here.